# How do I get the group name for a group chat in skype/teams?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I managed to get the conversation id with `session.message.address.conversation`.
It return this without any group name. How do I get the group name, I'm currently using Node.js?

```
{ 
    isGroup: true,
    id: '19:ccfa5044938747a09fcb8b85876b94eb@thread.skype' 
}
```

I'm currently using Microsoft Botframework SDK. 
The `session.message.address.conversation` is from the Microsoft Botframework SDK.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a bit more details so that someone might understand what exactly you need help with like which SDK you are using or which API you are calling to get these details etc.

Comment: Are you talking about Skype for Business or just Skype? I can see that Skype allows you to add a bot to a group chat. But  for Teams, that feature is still in developer preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations

Comment: @KyleDelaney Hi, thanks. It's for Skype.

Comment: What do you want to do with the name of the group?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney unfortunately yes, but then it's impossible to get the group name

Comment: The Skype team purposefully limits the information it sends to the bot, for security reasons. If you can explain what you want to do with the group name then I may be able to offer a workaround. Otherwise, would you please accept my answer?

Comment: Do you still need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no name is provided in the activity's conversation property then the name of the group cannot be accessed.